# How to populate ACF field via Axios post request during post creation?

Tags: vue.js, axios, advanced-custom-fields

how can I populate the ACF field while creating a post via Axios? With this method, I can create posts with the correct title and body but can't send ACF fields. (I already installed the ACF Rest Api plugin)

```
createPost(){
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://webisonstage.cloud/vuedeal/wp-json/wp/v2/prodotti',
          data: {
            title: this.form.title,
            content: this.form.message,
            acf:{
              prod_prezzo: this.form.prezzo
            }
          },
          headers: {
             "Authorization" : `Bearer ${this.$store.state.token}`
          }
        });
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing label "acf" to "fields"...